# Prove $V \subset \subset U$ implies the existance of $W$ such that $V \subset \subset W \subset \subset U$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

In a metric space $X$, we say that an open set $V$ is *compactly contained* in an open set $U$ if $\overline{V}$ is compact and $\overline{V} \subset U$. We write this as $V \subset \subset U$.

In Evans' book on PDEs, section 6.3.1, the proof of Theorem 1 starts by assuming that $V \subset \subset U$, and then choosing $W$ such that $V \subset \subset W \subset \subset U$.

Why is this choice justified? Why can we always choose $W$ such that this is true? Or is this only true in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which Evans' book works in, and not in any general metric space?

Comment: I suspect that, at the very least, the existence of $W$ requires local compactness of $X$.

Comment: For example, if $X=[0,1]\cup \mathbb Q$, then $V=(0,1)\subset\subset X$ but there is no such $W$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evans's PDE book is based on the setting of the Euclidean space ${\bf R}^n$, which is a *very* special metric space.

In general, this is true for any [locally compact Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) (LCH) space (see Folland's *Real Analysis*, Chapter 4):

> [image]